# trouble reinstalling ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had to uninstall then reinstall ruby.
When I went to install it the installation went off without a hitch except for a strange error:

```
ERROR: Error running 'bunzip2 '/home/tom/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.9.2-p180.tar.bz2'', please read /home/tom/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/extract.log
```

Now when I go to install rails it alerts me that I'm...

```
Missing RVM environment file: '/home/tom/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3tutorial'
```

I need to uninstall ruby, install zlib via `rvm install package zlib`, then install ruby 1.9.2.

Can anyone give me a walk through. I'm completely new and utterly confused. I've searched the web but can't find a walk through that works.

Comment: What OS are you using and what are the contents of `/home/tom/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p180/extract.log`

Comment: I'm using ubuntu and it says there's no such file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `rm -rf /home/tom/.rvm/` That will delete RVM and all installed packages. Reinstall RVM using the instructions from this page https://rvm.io

Comment: Make sure to of course read https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/packages/zlib/ additionally to the standard installation page.

Comment: Actually, make sure you have all the pre reqs for ruby installed on Ubuntu. There should be a page that is spit out after you run the install script with a list of packages.

Comment: A common problem is, indeed, the pre-requisites for RVM on Ubuntu.  Check out this post for a step by step on a clean install: http://blog.dcxn.com/2011/06/20/setting-up-rvm-on-ubuntu-11-04/